# How to configure UITableViewCell programmatically?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to create a `UITableView` from code (never done it this way before) which will be displayed in a `UIPopover`. I want to list the contents (filenames only) of a directory. This is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"FilenameCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[theTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel = fileList[0];

    return cell;
}
```

It's obviously not working, I'm getting an error: "Assignment to readonly property". So, the question is: How do I set the cell's data in this case?

Comment: the cast of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`'s result is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your `textLabel`'s `text` property (which I'm sure was just a typo in your case):

```
cell.textLabel.text = fileList[0];
```

Comment: Awww.. and I know better, too!  that fixed the problem... thank you... :-{